# How to draw line between some linear layouts?

Tags: android

I want to create a layout like the below picture.

I have four linear layout and I want to separate them with the black lines same the picture.

How can I create this??

[image]

Comment: A 9 patch set as the container's background might work pretty well.

Answer (score 4):

Add this between your horizontal layouts

```
<View
android:layout_width="5dp"
android:layout_height=“match_parent”
android:paddingTop=“16dp”
android:paddingBottom=“16dp"
android:background=“@android:color/black”/>
```

And this between you vertical ones

```
<View
android:layout_width=“match_parent"
android:layout_height=“5dp”
android:paddingRight=“16dp”
android:paddingLeft=“16dp"
android:background=“@android:color/black”/>
```

You’ll have to add these twice, as you have four layouts and hence four dividers.

Comment: but wont this not overlap his previous layouts? it will just push them to the side and there will be background showing through the spots where there is padding

Answer (score 2):

if you wanted to do it with just layouts you could make a frame layout which layers layouts and then have two layouts for vertical and horizontal and then add your layout in. i think this might be what you are looking for as this will put the lines overtop over your other views.

[image: example from xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <YOUR LAYOUT HERE/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="40dp"
                android:background="#ff000000" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="40dp"
                android:background="#ff000000" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <View
                android:layout_width="5dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="40dp"
                android:background="#ff000000" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <View
                android:layout_width="5dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="40dp"
                android:background="#ff000000" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: It's nice.but I have four different linear layout that any of them is clickable (by click in every color opens an activity). in your view there are just two linear layout (top and bottom)

Comment: they should still be clickable when doing this

Comment: but it doesn't work :( in every linear layout i use an Id and clickable property, but both of the top boxes show same activity and both of the bottom boxes show an activity. how can i fix them?

Comment: try setting android:clickable to false for everything thats not your layouts